# Biblatex clearfield does not work for editor and publisher

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to remove the 'Ed.by' field in the citation. However, I found the neither `\clearfield{editor}` nor `\clearlist{editor}` work in my case. My current setting is like

```
\AtEveryBibitem{% Clean up the bibtex rather than editing it
\clearfield{title}
\clearfield{eprint}
\clearfield{issn}
\clearfield{isbn}
\clearlist{location}
\clearlist{editor}
\clearfield{publisher}
 }
```

It seems everything is working except for the editor and publisher field. This is especially for `inproceeding` and `incollection` types.

one of the citations that does not work is attached below

```
@incollection{Farber2016Communication,
  title = {Communication and {{Communication Problems Between Autonomous Vehicles}} and {{Human Drivers}}},
  booktitle = {Autonomous {{Driving}}: {{Technical}}, {{Legal}} and {{Social Aspects}}},
  author = {Färber, Berthold},
  editor = {Maurer, Markus and Gerdes, J. Christian and Lenz, Barbara and Winner, Hermann},
  date = {2016},
  pages = {125--144},
  publisher = {{Springer}},
  location = {{Berlin, Heidelberg}},
  doi = {10.1007/978-3-662-48847-8_7},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-48847-8_7},
  urldate = {2023-09-17},
  isbn = {978-3-662-48847-8},
  langid = {english},
  keywords = {Autonomous Vehicle,Informal Rule,Police Officer,Road Traffic,Road User},
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you didn't provide an example for tests, but editor is a name and publisher a list, so you need \clearname and \clearlist.

Comment: Your comment works!